# Meaning of "But were Oedipa some single melted crystal of urban horse” from “The Crying of Lot 49”

Tags: meaning, thomas-pynchon, the-crying-of-lot-49

What does “But were Oedipa some single melted crystal of urban horse” mean?

Here is the full quote:

> What the road really was, she fancied, was this hypodermic needle, inserted somewhere ahead into the vein of a freeway, a vein nourishing the mainliner L.A., keeping it happy, coherent, protected from pain, or whatever passes, with a city, for pain. **But were Oedipa some single melted crystal of urban horse**, L.A., really, would be no less turned on for her absence.

Comment: It may help to know that "horse" is a slang term for heroin.

Comment: The sentence now makes sense, actually. Because it fits in nicely with the image of the road being a hypodermic needle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, and so that we have an answer present, "horse" is a slang term for [heroin](https://americanaddictioncenters.org/heroin-treatment/slang-names), so the simile being used is comparing the road to a hypodermic needle, and Oedipa as a dose of a drug, but one which would not be missed if not present.